# How to close serial port with disconnected device

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

my app communicates with arduino through serial port and controls if device is connected by timer.

Timer code:

```
if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Write("002");
            }
            catch
            {
                portRefresh.Stop(); // stop timer
                CloseSerialConnection(); // issue with disconnecting device
                label1.Text = "disconneced";
            }
```

It threws:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Device is not connected.

CloseSerialConnection code:

```
public void CloseSerialConnection()
    {
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort.Close();
        }
        serialPort.Dispose();


    }
```

I've googled it, but I haven't found anything working.

Comment: "my code always break" is not an appropriate problem description.  You must document the exception you get.  Do get out of the habit of writing code like this.  It is never correct to call Close() immediately after calling Write().  And it is never correct to call Open() immediately after Close(), that will always bomb your program.  Just stop closing the port, there's no point to it.  You close it when you are doing using it.  When your program ends.

Comment: ok, but it still not working

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're looking for.
Your topic says: "How to close serial port with disconnected device".
What I understand here is: you want to check when your device isn't plugged on USB. Is that it? Please be more accurate and the most succinct as possible.

Also: "Timer" is usually resource consuming; thus "Timer" is usually a bad idea to check things (unless no other way is available).

Answer (score -2):

You need to close the connection before Dispose().

```
if (serialPort.IsOpen)
{
    serialPort.Close();
}
serialPort.Dispose();
```

You also don't need to close and open the connection on the timer.
Open it once use it as long as you need and close it at the end.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Device is not connected.

On serialPort.Close();